# Diffie Hellman Exponentiation Implementation Problem

Tags: diffie-hellman

im trying to work on key agreement schemas on embeded systems. for diffie hellman, ive written a 256 bit multiplication, on AVR core it takes about 2 seconds on 1Mhz frequency, lets say my algorithm is weak and it'll work in 1/10 of this time. if we multiply the clock and say were working on 3Ghz PC, we have to exponentiate a 256 bit digit to a 256 bit digit, which means doing the multiplication 1.15e77 ( 2^256) time. with a simple relation, it'll take  e-4*1.15e77 seconds then?? right??? it is really to long to be practical? what am i missing out here?
ty for your answers!!

thanks for your usefull answers so far, but i think my question is a little diffirent!! im not asking a general question, im asking the exact implementation problem, pierre said i would need at most 256 time multiplication, but isn't the public key 256 bits?  then diffie hellman would need 2^256 time multiplication at most? what am i missong here?  thanks for your previous and upcomiong answers!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do institutions like banks do RSA with big primes?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13235/how-do-institutions-like-banks-do-rsa-with-big-primes)

Comment: Yeah, it's a dupe, but the original could really use a better answer. Of the three answers so far, one is buggy, one is (mostly) irrelevant and one takes *way* too long to get to the point.

Comment: BTW: this isn't actually related to your question, but Diffie-Hellman modulo a 256 bit prime is quite insecure.  To be secure, you really need at least 1024 bit Diffie-Hellman as an absolute minimum (with 2048 bit groups *strongly* encouraged).  Alternatively, you might want to consider Elliptic Curve groups; there, a 256 bit EC group is actually secure (but the equivalent of the multiplication (called addition there) is rather more compled)

Comment: As the question was not received clearly , it is about processing cost of a single exponentiation operation in the scale needed for diffie-hellman. as it is impractical to run it every time user requests a public key needing service like even opening a https web page, operating systems and browsers use PKI to manage the needed operations which are basically set of number generated from a trusted third party.

Comment: This should probably be a comment and definetly not an accepted answer. There is an abundance of evidence diffie hellman is practical and happen easily every time we open a secure connection. Obviously it can be done so the original question remains. What are you missing? The other answer by Pierre gives the most likely answer.

Comment: i read about implementation of cumbersome cryptography operations lately when i remembered my question which the answers did not cover my problem, as i had presented my rule of thumb calculation, many public key algorithms need a calculation beyond power of our PCs, which are redirected to PKIs, and as my problem was not how to speed up the operation, but how they are possible to implement in cases like embedded systems. pls do correct me if there are any mistakes or i misrepresented my problem in Question or the given answer.

Comment: Raising to the power of a n bit number does not take exponential time. It is far far more efficient see other answer.

Comment: i didnt mean exponential time, i meant exponentiation operation itself takes too much time, like taking a 256bit number to the power of a 256 bit number . and we know there are embedded systems using digital signatures a key agreement, how do they pull it off then? my understanding (from stalling : network security) was by using PKI. what am i missing out here?

Comment: Raising a number to the power of a 256 bit number requires only 256 square and multiply operations.  Not 2^256 operations.

Comment: PKI does not address the problem 'modular exponentiation is too expensive, how can I offload it'; instead, it addresses the problem 'how do I know who is associated with this public key (and what privileges do they have)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a well known technique for exponentation, you might read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method . The same techniques and its variants are used for matrix exponentiation ... You only need 256 squaring and at most 256 multiplications.

Comment: You will find the crypto algorithms algorithms for quite efficient implementations in the "Handbook of Applied Cryptography Book by A. J. Menezes, Alfred Menezes, Paul van Oorschot, and Scott Vanstone"